# Laravel 5.1 Model Create - Column not found: 1054

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to register a user using User model and calling the `create()` method and passing array of inputs but getting **Column not found: 1054**.

```
public function postRegister(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'email'     => $request->input('register-email'),
        'password'  => $request->input('register-password'),
        'lastname'  => $request->input('register-lastname'),
        'firstname' => $request->input('register-firstname'),
    ]);
}
```

The keys inside the `create()` method is my database `email, password, lastname, firstname` and I added 'register-' in my html inputs because I have another form that use the name 'email and password'

Comment: What is the complete error you get?

Comment: which Column not found ?

Answer (score 0):

so you can use the create method with array as a parameter, you must declare the columns in the fillable parameter

see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

you can also do it this way

```
$user = new User;
  $user->email = $request->input('register-email');
  $user->password = $request->input('register-password');
  $user->lastname = $request->input('register-lastname');
  $user->firstname = $request->input('register-firstname');
  $user->save();
```

Comment: While accurate, this probably wouldn't result in a MySQL 1054 error.